# Impact to profiles and certificates after apple developer program membership renewal

Tags: ios, membership, ad-hoc-distribution, renewal

I have a generic question related to the apple developer program membership renewal.My program will get expired in some days.I will be going for the renewal process.My profile and certificate will get expired along with the program.I want to know that with this renewal of the program for one more year will the profiles and certificate also get renewed for one more year.OR do I need to create new profiles and certificate in order to use it for my apps.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

Xcode transparently takes care of much of this, these days.  Xcode can automatically handle the profiles, and I believe it can also handle the certificates on your behalf.

All you have to do is renew your developer program membership.